# Optimize mysql if elseif and else logic

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

This part of MySQL stored procedure works but is very slow. Is there any way to optimize it?

```
IF (p_regid >0 AND p_submittedqueId>0 AND p_saveresponse=True)  then  
        if not exists(select * from  responseok where regid=p_regid AND QID =p_submittedqueId and TestId=p_TestId) AND (p_COption!='' or p_responsetext!='') then 

            insert into  responseok (regid,TestId,QID,Response,ResponseText,timestamp)  
            select p_regid,p_testId,p_submittedqueId,p_COption,p_responsetext,now(3);

         elseif (p_responsetext ='' AND p_COption='') then 
            insert into responsehistory (regid,TestId,QID,timestamp)  
            select p_regid,p_testId,p_submittedqueId,now(3);
            delete from  responseok where regid =p_regid and QID =p_submittedQueId AND TestId=p_TestId;
         else 
            insert into responsehistory (regid,TestId,QID,timestamp)  
            select p_regid,p_testId,p_submittedqueId,now(3);
            delete from  responseok where regid =p_regid and QID =p_submittedQueId AND TestId=p_TestId;
            insert into  responseok (regid,TestId,QID,Response,ResponseText,timestamp)  
            select p_regid,p_testId,p_submittedqueId,p_COption,p_responsetext,now(3);
         end if;
end if;
```

If I change the code to following, will it return the same results?

```
IF (p_regid >0 AND p_submittedqueId>0 AND p_saveresponse=True AND p_COption!='' or p_responsetext!='')  then  
        if not exists(select * from  responseok where regid=p_regid AND QID =p_submittedqueId and TestId=p_TestId) then

            insert into  responseok (regid,TestId,QID,Response,ResponseText,timestamp)  
            select p_regid,p_testId,p_submittedqueId,p_COption,p_responsetext,now(3);

         else 
            insert into responsehistory (regid,TestId,QID,timestamp)  
            select p_regid,p_testId,p_submittedqueId,now(3);
            delete from  responseok where regid =p_regid and QID =p_submittedQueId AND TestId=p_TestId;
        end if;
         else 
            insert into responsehistory (regid,TestId,QID,timestamp)  
            select p_regid,p_testId,p_submittedqueId,now(3);
            delete from  responseok where regid =p_regid and QID =p_submittedQueId AND TestId=p_TestId;
            insert into  responseok (regid,TestId,QID,Response,ResponseText,timestamp)  
            select p_regid,p_testId,p_submittedqueId,p_COption,p_responsetext,now(3);
         end if;
```

Will it improve the performance?

Will it be faster if I change the logic "if not exists" to something like "select 1 into some_var"?

Comment: Do you know if there are indexes on the regid, QID, and TestId columns in the responseok table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "if not exists" line is likely the culprit, it has to check an entire table to ensure each record does not match your criteria. Ensure that each column in that where clause (regid, QID, and TestId) each have indexes on them.  This should allow the DB engine to filter out records that don't match much faster.  Or you could consider trying to refactor so that you are only searching on a single indexed field.

Comment: @shantanuo A 'covering index' that includes regid, QID and TestID would be in your best interest.  This url may help with understanding - https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/04/06/speed-up-your-queries-using-the-covering-index-in-mysql